# How can I get manage_pages in Facebook Graph to make API calls for my page (personal use only)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a FB page that is a member of about 10 groups (all related to the same topic), and sometimes when I post I share the post to these groups.
Since it's so tedious to manually share the post to each group, I thought maybe using the API could be a better way to share my post into these specific groups my page is a member of. But FB seems to require that I enter some business details for a business that doesn't exist.

I don't own a business, this is a page to share educational tips and such. So I created an app (kept it in dev mode) and I'm the only administrator. I don't plan to make my app public, create an interface or have anyone else use it, and I don't intend to use it with any pages other than mine. Plus, I've already provided my personal ID so I am verified as an individual:

[image: personal verification]

But still, if I want to get manage_pages permission I'm required to go through some business verification and show FB how I'll use the API in a video, when I don't have any of this. In the verification page I'm requested to upload an icon, a privacy policy link and confirm commercial use:

[image: business verification required]

Should I just make up some fake business information so I can give them what they want? Is there not a way to use the API for personal use?

I'd be happy with just being able to send a couple cURLs to share my post through a terminal instead of having to do it via the FB GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement to complete review by business verification is to manage more than 3 pages per user, otherwise you can complete via individual verification. However you say pages and groups so it's not clear if you refer to publishing to a page feed or to a group (which requires additional permissions/features besides only manage_pages). And no, you shouldn't fake official documents just to complete business verification if you don't have a business...

Comment: I added some screenshots to my question. The thing is, I'm already verified as an individual, but I'm still being asked to go through business verification when requesting manage_pages. What I want to do is to be able to perform api call so I can share a page post (my own page) into groups the page is a member of. And I only want to do it just to avoid sharing it manually. This is noy an app that will be used by someone else and will not have any GUI.

Comment: You don't need to verify as business as long as your app's use hasn't changed. However publishing to a page requires publish_pages, not just manage_pages.